# Can I manually set session state to authenticated in embe simple auth?

Tags: django, session, authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am using session based authentication common for django application (subdomainA.example.com) and SPA consuming django API (subdomainB.exmaple.com).

I check certain artifact in my custom authenticator's restore methdo to determine either user is currently authenticated (certain cookie - seems poor solution but any idea how to do it better) and if yes, I would like to set ember simple auth session as authenticated.

How should I do it?
`this.set('session.isAuthenticated', true);`
seems not working fine, because on `invalidate` I got error:
ember.debug.js:16624 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Session#invalidate requires the session to be authenticated!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the ESA session to authenticated manually. Actually any attempt to write the `isAuthenticated` property should result in an error.

What you can do is to implement a custom authenticator and use that to authenticate the session with some static data that you pass to the `authenticate` method, e.g.

```
this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:my-authenticator', sessionData)

// app/authenticators/my-authenticator.js
…
authenticate(sessionData) {
  return Ember.RSVP.resolve(sessionData);
}
```

Comment: I wish there was more detail here. Where are we getting the sessionData from?